# Show & hide elements by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems to hide and show elements in a div by changing a select value.

There might be a better approach of doing this, but what I came up with was to use `data-` attributes to grab the elements I needed to manipulate.

But I don't get why my code doesn't work!

Here's a simplified version of my problem:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog">
    <form>
    <select id="form_type">
        <option data-show="type_0" data-hide="type_1" selected>Show 0</option>
        <option data-show="type_1" data-hide="type_0">Show 1</option>
    </select>
    <div data-visible="type_0" data-hidden="type_1">
        <input type="text" value="im visibible for type_0" />
    </div>
    <div data-visible="type_1" data-hidden="type_0" class="hidden">
        <input type="text" value="im visibible for type_1" disabled />
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#dialog').find('#form_type').on('change', function(){

    var self = $(this),
        selectedOption = self.find('option:selected'),
        showId = selectedOption.data("show"),
        hideId = selectedOption.data("hide"),
        parentForm = self.parents('form');

    parentForm
        .find('[data-visible="'+showId+'"]').removeClass('hidden')
        .find('input').prop('disabled', false);


    parentForm
        .find('[data-hidden="'+hideId+'"]').addClass('hidden')
        .find('input').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    visibility:none;
    display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4xo13mg/)

Thanks.

Comment: why use `$('#dialog').find('#form_type')` and not `$('#form_type')` where `#form_type` is an ID and should be unique in the dom ?

Comment: Just for future reference, you should include what you mean by *doesn't work* just to clarify for others. Otherwise this is a good question

Comment: Hacketo In my real code im having to grab the $('#form_type') from a stored variable, dialog.find('#form_type'). But I see your point.

RGraham If i knew what was wrong I wouldnt ask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while @Arun's answer is correct and will solve your problem, and will support more than 2 options.. and you should use it - it still doesn't answer what is the bug in your code..

The problem is that you keep hiding/showing the same element..

Looking at your HTML, you have 2 elements, with `data-visible` and `data-hidden` switched.

```
<div data-visible="type_0" data-hidden="type_1">
    <input type="text" value="im visibible for type_0" />
</div>
<div data-visible="type_1" data-hidden="type_0" class="hidden">
    <input type="text" value="im visibible for type_1" disabled />
</div>
```

So when you run the following javascript, both refer to the same object...

```
parentForm
    .find('[data-visible="'+showId+'"]').removeClass('hidden')
    .find('input').prop('disabled', false);


parentForm
    .find('[data-hidden="'+hideId+'"]').addClass('hidden')
    .find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Lets look at a specific example.

Lets assume showId is type_1, which means hideId is type_0..

The selector `[data-visible="type_1"]` and the selector `[data-hidden="type_0"]` point to the same element.

If you wish to keep the same logic and simply fix the bug you could do one of the following

- refer to showId or hideId but not both.
- refer to `data-visible` or `data-hidden` but not both.

The first option means to change the code to:

```
parentForm
    .find('[data-visible="'+showId+'"]').removeClass('hidden')
    .find('input').prop('disabled', false);


parentForm
    .find('[data-hidden="'+showId+'"]').addClass('hidden')
    .find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

and the second option means changing the code to

```
parentForm
    .find('[data-visible="'+showId+'"]').removeClass('hidden')
    .find('input').prop('disabled', false);


parentForm
    .find('[data-visible="'+hideId+'"]').addClass('hidden')
    .find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

either of which should solve the problem.

- fiddle for first solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jq4d709q/
- fiddle for the second solution: https://jsfiddle.net/x0dj1gce/

This explains why your code does not work. 
For production, please use Arun's solution.

Comment: Thanks this clarified what I did wrong, Im having another logic in the same form that needs other show/hide references so this works better in my case. Ty!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to have 2 attributes, since you will show only 1 at any time, you can hide all other `data-visible` elements

```js
$('#form_type').on('change', function() {

  var self = $(this),
    selectedOption = self.find('option:selected'),
    showId = selectedOption.data("show"),
    parentForm = self.closest('form'),
    $el = parentForm.find('[data-visible="' + showId + '"]');

  parentForm.find('[data-visible]').not($el).addClass('hidden').find('input').prop('disabled', true);


  $el.removeClass('hidden')
    .find('input').prop('disabled', false);

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">
  <form>
    <select id="form_type">
      <option data-show="type_0" selected>Show 0</option>
      <option data-show="type_1">Show 1</option>
    </select>
    <div data-visible="type_0">
      <input type="text" value="im visibible for show_0" />
    </div>
    <div data-visible="type_1" class="hidden">
      <input type="text" value="im visibible for show_1" disabled />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah smart using the .not(). Thanks

Comment: @oBo The problem is the `showId` and `hideId` it selects the same element.. so first you removed the hidden class then adds it back