# Replace div with another div (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have PartialView

Here is code

```
  <div id="question1" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question1)
</div>
<div id="question2" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question2)
</div>
<div id="question3" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question3)
</div>
<div  id="question4" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question4)
</div>
```

I call PartialView via AJAX

Code here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var full_url = document.URL; // Get current url
    var url_array = full_url.split('/') // Split the string into an array with / as separator
    var id = url_array[url_array.length - 1];  // Get the last part of the array (-1)



    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/interwier/QuestionBlock",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#questions").html(data);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Smth wrong in controller");
        }
    });
});
```

How I can display div with id=question1 when I click button replace it with div with id= question2? Button is not in PartialView.

**Update**

I decide to change logic and delete PartialView

I make code in div like this

```
 <div id="questions" class="qustion-div-one">
        <div id="question1" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question1)
        </div>
        <div id="question2" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question2)
        </div>
        <div id="question3" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question3)
        </div>
        <div id="question4" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question4)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need on button click make `question1` hidden, and `question2` visible, on next click `question2` will be hidden and `question3` visible and etc.

Or just simple remove `question1` and change  for `question2` etc.

How I can do this?

**UPDATE 2**

I try to do this script

```
 $('#next').click(function () {
    $('#questions>div').toggle();
});
```

but it opens all 3 divs, but i need question2 div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this many ways or you can also utilise the collapsible panels to show the questions.

Below is the simple approach to do this.

CSS class.

```
.inactive {  display:none; }

.active { display:block; }
```

In html at the bottom add button

```
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

On page ready you need to write below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#questions div').attr( "class", "inactive" );
    $('#questions div:first-child').attr( "class", "active" );
});

$('#next').click(function() {
  var div = $('#questions div.active');
  div.attr("class", "inactive");
  if(div.next().length>0){
     div.next().attr( "class", "active");
  }
  else{
    $('#questions div:first-child').attr( "class", "active" );
  }
});
```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/a0du6u5d/1/

Comment: Try your code but when I paste html, all divs are visible

Comment: have you added css class 'active' & 'inactive' in style tag on your html?

Comment: Nope , in css file.

Comment: Is that css included on your html?

Comment: same you can do without css , updated the link for your refference https://jsfiddle.net/a0du6u5d/2/

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain better what your desired result would be in this case? Maybe what you want is to replace the JQuery `$.ajax` call with the JQuery method `load` ([Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load)), see "Loading Page Fragments" sub title. You could dynamically construct the "suffixed selector expression" to replace a specific part of your page, e.g.

```
$( "#question1" ).load( "/interwier/QuestionBlock #question2" );
```

But I'm not sure I got your question right.

Comment: I now will Update my post.

Comment: I Updated my post

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this: decorate your div with a data-* attribute, like data-position, and another attribute on #next button like a counter :

```
<div id="questions" class="qustion-div-one" data-pos="1">
    <div id="question1" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question1)
    </div>
    <div id="question2" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none" data-pos="2">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question2)
    </div>
    <div id="question3" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none" data-pos="3">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question3)
    </div>
    <div id="question4" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:10px; display:none" data-pos="4">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Question4)
    </div>
</div>

<button id="next" data-target"1">Next</button>
```

Then on click you increment data-target if < of number of divs.
Something like this older question

[Show & hide elements by data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802861/show-hide-elements-by-data-attribute)